# Programming C# array multiplication

Tags: c#, arrays, multiplication

I have a function that takes a string and returns a string. In it, I convert the string into an integer array and later try to multiply every other number like this:

```
private string addEveryOther(string x) 
{    
    int[] d = x.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        d[i] = d[i] * 2;
        MessageBox.Show(d[i].ToString()); //Display the result? 
        i++;
    }

    // And later returning a string:
    StringBuilder g = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (int n in d)
    {
        g.Append(Convert.ToChar(n));
    }

    return g.ToString();
}
```

This works with addition, but not with multiplication as it returns strange values. If I input "3434343434" i expect it to return "6464646464". Now it returns: "f4f4f4f4f4" and I don't know why? Any suggestions how to go about it?

Comment: What happens with multiplication, compared with what you'd expect?

Comment: In the for loop, you are incrementing i both in the head and inside the block. Is this intentional?

Comment: What do you expect to achieve when multiplying **Unicode codes**?

Comment: Anders Gustafsson: Yes, to choose every other number and not every one. (so that i += 2 each round)

Comment: "What happens with multiplication, compared with what you'd expect? – Jon Skeet"
It returns strange values, eg. "98" if i put in "1" (which should return 1). didn't think that i was multiplying unicode chars.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect to happen. I suspect you are using convert when you actually mean to parse the value to an integer and then just get the string value back. Are you sure you want to use the Convert class here?

Comment: I expect that string "1212121212" should return "1414141414" etc, but now i returns "b2b2b2b2b2". Maybe the Convert dosen't work like i Thought. I thought it was OK because addition works fine, but not multiplication.

Comment: [Convert.ToInt32(char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871.aspx) Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer. So when you converting "0" result will be 48, when "1" result 50 and so on. At first to convert correctly dirty hack: `Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussions above, I suppose your method should use ToString instead of Convert.ToChar.

```
private string addEveryOther(string x) 
{    
  int[] d = x.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString())).ToArray();

  for(int i = 0; i < d.Length; i += 2)
  {
    d[i] = d[i] * 2;
    MessageBox.Show(d[i].ToString()); //Display the result? 
  }

  // And later returning a string:
  return String.Concat(d.Select(n => n.ToString()));
}
```

EDIT: Using @Kirill's Concat solution and @Reniuz comment in the addEveryOther method should hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, its better but still returns "bad" values: "1004910049100491004910049" for "2121212121". Why is 4 translated as 100, and 1 as 49?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString()) as Reniuz suggested works for that. int[] d = x.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString())).ToArray();

Comment: I have modified the array creation according to @Reniuz comment above, does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comment [Convert.ToInt32(char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871.aspx)

> Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the
>   equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

So when you converting "0" result will be 48, when "1" result 50 and so on.

Here's changed code:

```
private string addEveryOther(string x)
{
    //1. Convert string to int, not char to int
    int[] d = x.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString())).ToArray();

    //2. start from second number
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        d[i] = d[i] * 2;
        MessageBox.Show(d[i].ToString()); //Display the result? 
        i++;
    }
    string s = d.ToString();
    // And later returning a string:
    StringBuilder g = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (int n in d)
    {
        //3. Convert int to string, not to char
        g.Append(n.ToString());
    }

    return g.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int[] d = x.Select(n => int.Parse(n.ToString())).ToArray();      
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)     
    {         
        d[i] = (i%2 == 0? d[i] * 2 : d[i]);
    }      
    StringBuilder g = new StringBuilder();     
    foreach (int n in d)    
    {         
        g.Append(n);    
    }      
    return g.ToString();
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
 Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString())
```

There is redundant conversion. I think the simplest way is

```
var d = x.Select(n => Char.IsDigit(n) ? n - '0' : 0).ToArray();
```